# PHP, Unidentified variable in a class

Tags: php, class, variables

I am trying to get a class working but for some reason I cannot get find the variables I have built into the class. Here is the code for the class: class file url (cls_question_object.php)

```
class question_object{

// the id to the question
public $i_id = "";

// the question string
public $s_qString = "";

// the question type
public $s_qType = "";

/* the array of answer strings
*/
public $a_qAnswerStrings = array();
    public $a_qAnswerSet = array("id"=>"","string"=>"");

}
```

And here is the code that I am testing my class with: file url (test_question_object.php)

```
include("cls_question_object.php");

/* - test for class question object -
*/

$cls_obj = new question_object;
$cls_obj->$i_id = "1";
$cls_obj->$s_qString = "test question string";
$cls_obj->$s_qType = "fib";
$cls_obj->$$a_qAnswerStrings[0]['id'] = "0";
$cls_obj->$$a_qAnswerStrings[0]['string'] = "test answer string";

print_r($cls_obj);
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: i_id in C:\wamp\www\Exam Creator\test_question_object.php on line 9
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your variables with things like `i_` for integers or `s_` for strings. That is an incredibly out-dated practice, and has particularly little value in PHP where the type of a variable can and will change to suit its use. You're only going to produce ugly, difficult to maintain code this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these instance variables by doing:

```
$cls_obj->i_id = "1";
```

rather than:

```
$cls_obj->$i_id = "1";
```

However it is generally not good practice to make instance variables public, rather make them private and make [mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

You would do something like this:

```
private $i_id = "";

public function getId(){
  return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id){
  $this->id = $id;
}
```

and you would access these functions like this:

```
$cls_obj = new question_object();
$cls_obj->setId(5);
$id = $cls_obj->getId();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will definitely put this into practice.

Answer (score 1):

$obj->$field_name this wrong, please use $obj->field_name to access your object's field.
in your case it's should be used like this:

```
$cls_obj = new question_object;
$cls_obj->i_id
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question. Doing it the other way means it will try to access the class variable that has the name of the value stored in $i_id - Kind of like how $$var works. There is no $i_id - hence your undefined notice.